# Detect virtual desktop in Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, swing, windows-virtual-desktop

In Java, is there a way to determine if my frame is on the current virtual desktop or on one that is not currently visible?

The app has some popup frames (notifications), that display and I do not want them to display unless it is on the desktop where my main frame is located. I could ask the user via a `JOptionPane`, but it causes my desktop to switch over to the main frame.

Comment: I updated the question.  I have some popup frames, aka notifications, that display and I do not want them to display unless it is on the desktop where my main frame is located.  Also if a JOptionPane displays it causes my desktop to switch over to the main frame.

Comment: Have you tried to check whether the frame reports to be visible if not on the current desktop? My hunch is it won’t.